# Comparison arguments must be compatible types: System.Address, String

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, fields

I created an apex controller class and i am trying to upload ot to salesforce, i receive many errors, one of them is:"Comparison arguments must be compatible types: System.Address, String" and "Field is not writeable: Contact.Name (30:50)" same error with MailingAddress field. From what i know you can edit the  name of a contact and its MailingAddress, i´ll leave my code down below:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Object> searchContacts(String seachTerm) {

 List <Contact> result= ([SELECT id,Name,Phone,MailingAddress,Email,Title,Birthdate FROM contact where Name like: '%' + seachTerm +'%']);

  return result;

}
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void deleteContact(String conToDelete){

    Contact result=  ([SELECT id, Name,Phone,MailingAddress,Email,Title,Birthdate FROM contact where Name like: '%' + conToDelete +'%']);
try{
    delete result;
    
}catch(DmlException e){

    system.debug(e);

}
}
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void editContact(Contact Contact){

    Contact editContact=Contact;
    if(editContact.Name!=null || editContact.Name!=''){
    Contact result= ([SELECT  id,Name,Phone,MailingAddress,Email,Title,Birthdate FROM contact where Name like:'%' + editContact.Name +'%']);

    if(editContact.Name!=result.Name){result.Name=editContact.Name;}
    if((editContact.Phone!=null || editContact.Phone!='') && editContact.Phone!=result.Phone){result.Phone=editContact.Phone;}
    if((editContact.MailingAddress!=null || editContact.MailingAddress!='') && editContact.MailingAddress!=result.MailingAddress){result.MailingAddress=editContact.MailingAddress;}
    if((editContact.Email!=null || editContact.Email!='') && editContact.Email!=result.Email){result.Email=editContact.Email;}
    if((editContact.Title!=null || editContact.Title!='') && editContact.Title!=result.Title){result.Title=editContact.Title;}
    if((editContact.Birthdate!=null || editContact.Birthdate!='') && editContact.Birthdate!=result.Title){result.Birthdate=editContact.Birthdate;}

    try{
        update result;
        
    }catch(DmlException e){

        system.debug(e);

    }

}

}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `MailingAddress` is a address datatype in salesforce and you have compared that with String. `editContact.MailingAddress != ''`
   Also you cannot set address like this. You need to set each and every attribute of address separately.
2. Same for `Birthdate`, its a date field and you have compared that with String. `editContact.Birthdate != ''`
3. `Name` in Contact is a compound field, which means it consists of `FirstName` and `LastName`. So you cannot set `Name`, directly, you can only set `FirstName` and `LastName`.

NOTE: Change your input variable from `Contact Contact` from `Contact incomingContact`

Comment: So checking out the MailingAddress and The Birthdate should be enough or could i use something else to evaluate if is empty? I tries isEmpy() but apparently works only for Strings as well. Thanks for your help!!